# How can I properly retrieve data from a ListBox of Objects and Filter it using a ComboBox with Lambda Expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lambda, listbox

I'm developing a Windows Form project where I have a class called **Client** which has its properties and a static list. I also have a Form where you register new Clients which I am 101% sure is correct so I won't post its code here. Every time you register a client, it is added to the static List.

The problem is in a Form that I have for Listing clients. This form has a **ListBox** that should show you all the **ids** of the registered clients, a **'Check Button'** used for displaying all the information of the selected client (selected id in the listbox) that has next to it a group of labels. 
Under all the mentioned things I have a **ComboBox** which has 2 options: *Male* and *Female*. This ComboBox it is used to filter the Ids that are only of the selected sex.

[List Clients Form IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltjvq.png)

I've had lots of problems with Listing and filtering the Clients:

1- My first problem came when I tried to add to the ListBox all the Registered Clients, I first tried using different **Lambda expressions** ( like this one: Lista.Items.Add(Client.clients.Find(i => i.Id==i.Id).Id) but I couldn't do it, it partially worked with a expression that filled the ListBox with the same ID over and over again. Then after researching a lot and reading lots of different questions I used the **DataSource** property of ListBox to 'bind' the Client list with my ListBox but I had to change this way of doing it because I couldn't *update* the ListBox as I wanted when filtering the data (updating datasource).

So afterwards I changed that and used instead a **foreach loop** to fill the ListBox.

When I used the DataSource to fill the ListBox instead of the foreach, I didn't have any problem when Checking the info of a Client and displaying it in the Form, but when I use the foreach loop to fill the ListBox (both methods should fill the ListBox in the same way I guess) I can't display the information of a Client using the same methods (in `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` method) and I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. Why does this happen? How can I fix this?

2- The other big problem is when filtering IDs, as seen in the below code I tried filling the ListBox with datasource property and with a foreach with the filtered IDs but I couldn't manage to do the Lambda expression for filtering the IDs nor filling or removing objects from the list.

What is the best way to fill the list in this case? If I want to use a Lambda expression to fill the ListBox with the IDs registered in the static list that won't cause me problems filtering the IDs in the Combobox how should it be? (I just want to learn about this).

Please read the code with its comments to understand even more.

Also check the image please

```
class Client
{
    private string id; 
    private string name;
    private byte idSex; // 1= Male    2= Female

    public string Name
    {
        get {return name; }
        set {this.name= value; }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set { this.id= value; }
    }

    public byte IdSex
    {
        get { return this.idSex; }
        set { this.idSex = value; }
    }


    public static List<Client> clients = new List<Client>(); //Clients are added here

    public Client(string id, string name, byte idSex)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.idSex=idSex;
    }
}


public partial class ListadoClientes : Form //ignore the name, I translated everything to English because I speak Spanish
{
    public ListadoClientes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> sexos = new List<string>(){ "Male", "Female" };

        Lista.Items.Clear();//NOTE: 'Lista' is the name of the ListBox*****

        /*Lista.DataSource = Client.clients; commented because I couldn't update the listbox when I wanted to filter the data and fill the listbox again but with IDs of only one sex*/


        foreach(Client c in Client.clients)
        {
            Lista.Items.Add(c);
        }
        Lista.DisplayMember = "Id";
        Lista.ValueMember = "Id";

        foreach(string s in sexos)//adding the gender to the combobox
        {

            ComboSexo.Items.Add(s); //ComboSexo is the name of the Combobox

            /* string y = Lista.GetItemText(Lista.TopIndex+1);
                Lista.Items.Add(Client.clients.Find(i => i.Id!= y).Id); >>>>HERE I TRIED TO USE A LAMBDA EXPRESSION, USED OTHERS TOO*/
        }
    }

    private void ListadoClientes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //not used
    }

    private void Lista_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //not used       
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //THIS CODE WORKS FOR DISPLAYING INFO IN THE LABELS WHEN USING THE DATASOURCE PROPERTY FOR FILLING THE LISTBOX BUT IT DOESN'T WORK WITH THE FOREACH WAY.
        string sex;// 1= Male 2= Female


        //code below to save the sex of the client to a string value depending on its id
        if (Cliente.clientes.Find(i => Lista.SelectedValue == i.Id).IdSex == 1)
        {
            sex = "Male";
        }
        else
        {
            sex = "Female";
        }

        LblId.Text = Client.clients.Find(i => Lista.SelectedValue == i.Id).Id;
        LblName.Text = Client.clients.Find(i => Lista.SelectedValue == i.Id).Name;
        LblSex.Text = sex;
    }

    private void ComboSexo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void BtnFiltrarSexo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ComboSexo.Text == "Male")
        {

            /*Lista.Items.Clear();
                Lista.DataSource = Client.clients.Find(i=> i.IdSex==2);
                Lista.DisplayMember = "Id";
                Lista.ValueMember = "Id";
                Tried to do this at first when I had the listbox filled with the DataSource*/


            /*int y=Client.clients.Count;
                for(int i=0; i<y;i++)
                {
                    if ()
                    {
                        Lista.Items.Remove(c);
                >>>did not work<<<

                }*/
            /*Lista.Items.Remove(Client.clients.Find(i=> i.IdSex!=1 )); I also tried to Remove using a Lambda Expression but this worked only removing 1 Client!! then I tried using a for loop or a foreach but I couldn't do it.

            }
            else if(ComboSexo.SelectedText == "Female")
            {
                Lista.Items.Clear();
                Lista.DataSource = Client.clients.Find(i=> i.IdSex==2);
                Lista.DisplayMember = "Id";
                Lista.ValueMember = "Id";
                //this won't work also
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error you must select a sex");
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

P.S : The IDs in the list are displayed like : 123, 345 , 864 ,etc etc so if you filter by sex let's say that only the id 345 is a male, then after clicking the 'Filter button ' the list box will show only the id 345.

Comment: possible for you to make this shorter and more to the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Fill All Clients

```
        Lista.Items.Clear();
        Lista.Items.AddRange(Client.clients.ToArray());
```

To Fill only Male

```
        Lista.Items.Clear();
        Lista.Items.AddRange(Client.clients.Where(x => x.IdSex == 1).Select(x => x).ToArray());
```

To Fill only Female

```
        Lista.Items.Clear();
        Lista.Items.AddRange(Client.clients.Where(x => x.IdSex == 2).Select(x => x).ToArray());
```